# xelement.load blank values when run on device but populated when run in emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm using

```
XElement xmlWeather = XElement.Load(streamResult)
```

to load in a weather file. I then parse values out of it for my program.
At one time this code worked on my Windows 7.1 phone as well as my wife's 8.1 version.
When I run the code in the emulator and view the file, all expected tags and values are present.
However, when I run the code against my 7.1 device - which I say again used to work just fine - it now shows the xml coming across as missing all values (either blank or showing up as NA) in the latter part of the file (where current weather is); the first part of the file (forecasts) is all fine. NOTE the tags in the latter are exactly the same, it is only the values that are missing.

I am also seeing this only in running the program. I built a much smaller, test program stripped of all that wasn't needed - and that one works as expected against both emulator and device.

Short of turning to MS Support, I'm not certain how to fix/address.  Anyone seen this issue before? I could entertain switching to a different way to read in the file, but would rather first understand why it is now failing in this way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. We probably can't help you unless you show us the actual code you tried. Is that line above the only line of code that is relevant here? do you have some config to tell your code how to load the result? (note: I am not a mobile dev, just reviewing your question)? If there is anything else relevant to your question, can you please edit your question and add it there?

Comment: Note: I'd check to see if the place that publishes the weather-data has changed their API recently...